# Removing Duplicates in Two Columns (No Combination)

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Input <- data.frame(ID  = c("1",   "2",  "3",  "4",  "5",  "6",  "7",  "8"),
                    V1  = c("A1", "A1", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3",  "G1" ),
                    V2  = c("A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G1",  "G3" ))
```

I want to remove **rows** where (single) observations in two columns 'V1' and 'V2' are duplicated **irrespective** of whether the (single) particular observation is in 'V1' or 'V2'.
The results should look like this (e.g.,  A1 occurs in row 2 and 3: delete rows 2 and 3).

```
Output <- data.frame(ID  = c("1",   "4"),
                     V1  = c("A1", "G3"),
                     V2  = c("A1", "G2"))
```

Comment: Perhaps `t(apply(Input[-1], 1, sort)) -> m1;
> !(duplicated(m1)|duplicated(m1, fromLast = TRUE)) -> i1; Input[i1,]`

Comment: Thank you, but the code is not working. And if I adjust the code, row 5 is still listed (which is wrong given G3 in row 4)

Comment: Row 5 should be dropped given that G3 occurs in row 4.

Comment: To sum up: row 1 and 4 should remain (all other rows should be dropped).

Comment: I think *duplicates* suggests that the first occurrence is not a duplicate, only those (matching) that follow.

Comment: @r2evans: Exactly.

Comment: If row 4 stays because "G3" is new, then shouldn't row 2 stay because of "G2"?

Comment: @r2evans: No, because row 2 (and 3) include A1 (and since it's a row-wise duplicate check, row 2 (and 3) must be removed because A1 occurs in row 1). (BTW: row 4 includes G2 and G3, but both occur then for the first time).

Comment: Row 4's "G2" occurs in row 3 as well, so it is not the first time. However, it sounds like you have a *rolling dependency*: row `n` is only checked as a duplicate after rows `1:(n-1)` have been deduplicated. Good luck, Dan, this just screams horrible performance at scale.

Comment: Thanks. But, it's not necessarily rolling because of the succesive removal of rows.

Comment: *successive removal of rows* to me specifically means *rolling*. Regardless, I think you really need to clarify your question to indicate this fact, since this behavior is in contrast to normal R `duplicated` behavior.

Comment: @r2evans: Thanks. But do you have an answer?

Comment: Yes, but what I think will answer your *needs* will not answer your question *as asked*. The logic of your description is incomplete, and somebody who comes after you and interprets just the question **and not these comments** may try the answer and get it all wrong. Always (please) keep the question complete and self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can tolerate not having factors in your data,

```
Input <- data.frame(ID  = c("1",   "2",  "3",  "4",  "5",  "6",  "7",  "8"),
                    V1  = c("A1", "A1", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3",  "G1" ),
                    V2  = c("A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G1",  "G3" ),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

then you can use this:

```
ind <- Reduce(function(lgl, i) {
  lgl[i] <- lgl[i] && !any(Input[i,-1] %in% unlist(Input[which(head(lgl,i-1)),-1]))
  lgl
}, seq_len(nrow(Input))[-1], init=rep(TRUE, nrow(Input)))

Input[ind,]
#   ID V1 V2
# 1  1 A1 A1
# 4  4 G3 G2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try recursion that calls itself while there are still rows that could be duplicates. This is very dangerous as corrupted input will make it run till no memory is left.

```
removeDuplicates <- function(data) {
    rm <- c(data[1, ]$V1, data[1, ]$V2)
    dataAfter <- subset(data[seq_len(nrow(data))[-1], ], !V1 %in% rm & !V2 %in% rm)
    return(rbind(data[1, ], 
                 if (nrow(dataAfter) > 1) {
                    removeDuplicates(dataAfter)
                 } else {
                    NULL
                 }
     ))
}

removeDuplicates(Input)
  ID V1 V2
1  1 A1 A1
4  4 G3 G2
```

Input data (modified to remove factors):

```
Input <- data.frame(ID  = c("1",   "2",  "3",  "4",  "5",  "6",  "7",  "8"),
                    V1  = c("A1", "A1", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G3",  "G1" ),
                    V2  = c("A1", "G2", "A1", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G1",  "G3" ),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```